# Problema con un codigo utilizando map

Tags: javascript, reduce

tengo problemas con este ejercicio, aplique map pero no se si esta aplicado de la forma correcta o si es el metodo indicado para llegar al final del problema, tengo entendido que con el map puedo retornar el nombre:el numero del salario ,pero no me estaría funcionando

```
function salarioAnual(empleados, nombre) {
  // Escribe una funcion que reciba un arreglo de objetos con info de empleados (empleados)
  // y un string (nombre)
  // y retorne el salario anual del empleado con ese nombre;
  // ej: 
  // var empleados = [{
  //    nombre: 'Manuel',
  //    salario: 1000,
  //  },
  //  {
  //    nombre: 'Flor',
  //    salario: 4000,
  //  },
  //  {
  //    nombre: 'Maria',
  //    salario: 500,
  //  }
  // ];
  // salarioAnual(empleados, 'Flor'); => 48000
  // salarioAnual(empleados, 'Manuel;); => 12000
  // Tu código aca:`
```

lo que realice yo es lo siguiente

```
var empleados = [{
  nombre: nombre,
  salario: 1000,
},
{
  nombre: nombre,
  salario: 4000,
},
{
  nombre: nombre,
  salario: 500,
}]

var anual = empleados.map(function(salario){

  return{
    salario: empleados.salario * 12
  }
})
return anual
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto seria la solución clásica, sin map:

```javascript
function salarioAnual(empleados, nombre) {
  for (let i = 0; i < empleados.length; i++) {
    if (empleados[i].nombre == nombre) {
      return empleados[i].salario * 12
    }
  }
}
```

Básicamente ejecutas un bucle con el array de objetos `empleados`, llamando a cada elemento del array mediante su índice, gracias al incremento de la variable `i`, y cuando encuentras el nombre retornas el valor del cálculo deseado y sales del bucle y de la función.

Aquí te dejo un snippet con todo funcionando:

```js
var empleados = [{
    nombre: 'Manuel',
    salario: 1000,
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Flor',
    salario: 4000,
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Maria',
    salario: 500,
  }
];

function salarioAnual(empleados, nombre) {
  for (let i = 0; i < empleados.length; i++) {
    if (empleados[i].nombre == nombre) {
      return empleados[i].salario * 12
    }
  }
}

console.log(salarioAnual(empleados, 'Flor'))
console.log(salarioAnual(empleados, 'Manuel'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás iterando y reasignando TODOS los elementos del array, después devuelves el array entero, mientras que lo que te piden es simplemente devolver el salario anual individual según la persona que te señalen

Para esto, simplemente puedes usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
function salarioAnual(empleados, nombre) {
  return empleados.filter(e => e.nombre === nombre)[0].salario * 12;
}

const empleados = [{nombre: "Flor", salario: 1000}, {nombre: "Manuel", salario: 4000}];

console.log(
  salarioAnual(empleados, "Flor"), // 12000
  salarioAnual(empleados, "Manuel"), // 48000
);
```

Comment: mira prove este otro codigo pero aun sigue sin funcionar : var anual = empleados.map(x => x.salario * 12) . ya que la idea es que pase por todos los nombres

Comment: `empleados.map(e => e.salario * 12)[empleados.findIndex(e => e.nombre === nombre)];`

Comment: y a que hace referencia el [0]?

Comment: Cuando usas `filter()` el método te devuelve un array diferente, el que incluye solo los elementos con el criterio que le hemos dado. Evidentemente, después de filtrar el array principal, tendremos un array con un solo elemento que es el objeto de la persona que buscamos, el `[0]` hace referencia a ese objeto, es decir; el primer elemento.

Comment: Quedo clarisimo , te agradezco.